# PHP: Streaming Images Outside of Webroot and Caching

Tags: php, caching

I'm using Apache and when I request an image directly for the first time, the status of the image is "200 OK". Subsequent requests have a status of "304 Not Modified", which is good because it saves bandwidth for both the client and server.

I'm working on a website that will allow users to upload images. These images need to be stored outside of the webroot not just to prevent hotlinking, but also so I can collect statistics on the images. So my thought was to use a PHP script like this to stream the images:

```
<?php

    $image_to_stream = '/path/outside/of/webroot/image.jpg';
    $cache_seconds = 2592000; // 30 days

    header("Cache-Control: max-age=$cache_seconds");
    header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + $cache_seconds) . ' GMT');
    header('Pragma: cache');
    header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
    header('Content-length: ' . filesize($image_to_stream));

    readfile($image_to_stream);

?>
```

However, the script appears to always have a status of "200 OK" and the entire image gets streamed. Is there a way to fix this or should I be taking another approach or what? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the `If-Modified-Since` request header.

Basically, check the timestamp on that file locally.  If it has changed since the date specified in the `If-Modified-Since` header, return it.  Otherwise, send bac, a 304 not modified.

From the RFC:

> A GET method with an If-Modified-Since header and no Range header requests that the identified entity be transferred only if it has been modified since the date given by the If-Modified-Since header. The algorithm for determining this includes the following cases:
>
> a) If the request would normally result in anything other than a
>            200 (OK) status, or if the passed If-Modified-Since date is
>            invalid, the response is exactly the same as for a normal GET.
>            A date which is later than the server's current time is
>            invalid.
>
> b) If the variant has been modified since the If-Modified-Since
>            date, the response is exactly the same as for a normal GET.
>
> c) If the variant has not been modified since a valid If-
>            Modified-Since date, the server SHOULD return a 304 (Not
>            Modified) response.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

You can send that with this PHP code:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified', true, 304);
```

Comment: But if you want to save bandwidth then *don't forget to supply new Cache-control / expires headers!*